# define migration folder when adding migration using Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, migration

Before I was using Windows command line to add migrations and it was working properly.

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName -o Data\Migrations
```

I tried using Package Manager Console like:

```
add-migration "MigrationName"
```

This adds the migration successfully but to the project main folder not to the Data folder.

How can I tell it to add the migration to the Data folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify path in outputDir option

> add-migration InitialIdentityModel-v1 -OutputDir ".\Data\Migrations\"